# Running all tests in IntelliJ, howto

Tags: junit, intellij-idea, testng

It seems that i can either run all `jUnit` tests or all `TestNG` tests in my case

Is it possible to create a single test which will cover both `jUnit` and `testNG`?

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to mix test framworks in a single project ?

Comment: Well, i am not the only author :), but there are some things testNG does cleaner then jUnit (for example dataprovider) logic that i use

Comment: Completely not an answer but... why won't you just agree on testing framework? It starts from TestNG and JUnit side-by-side, continues with multiple mocking frameworks and at the end you get a product using GWT and Wicket, both accessing both Hibernate, EclipseLink and iBatis. And back to your question, `maven-surefire-plugin` also used to have issues with JUnit/TestNG together.

Comment: Sometimes, choice is a privilege one does not have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From IDEA this is impossible. I suggest that you run your tests with Maven or similar and execute them both. You can also view test coverage with Emma, even mixed, I think.

Comment: Yes, this is how i do it today. Since IDEA generates coverage amongst other things i wanted to get a consolidated report

Comment: This is what I wanted to say. Generate a consolidated report with the maven Emma plugin.